# crontab only works in tmp directory

Tags: python, cron

I am trying to use crontab to run a python script.

Here is what I put into the crontab -e

`* * * * * path/to/python /Users/myname/Desktop/script.py`

However, it does not run the script unless I put the python script in /tmp/:

`* * * * * path/to/python /tmp/script.py`

Does anyone know how to make crontab run a python file that is on my Desktop, not in the /tmp directory?

This is my python3 script I am trying to run:

```
from pync import Notifier
import os


Notifier.notify('notification', group=os.getpid())
```

Comment: have you tried using an _absolute_ path like ```/Users/myname/Desktop/script.py```?

Comment: Yes, I have and it does not work. @mrxra

Comment: Try * * * * * path/to/python /Users/myname/Desktop/script.py >> /some/path/to/file.log 2>&1 to log the output of the cron. This will show the error most likely.

Comment: It says it can't open the .py and the error is [Errno 1] Operation not permitted @Torben545

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Since I am on macOS Catalina here is what you do.

Go to system preferences, security & privacy, click the lock to make changes, click full disk access, select the plus, add in cron (located at /usr/sbin/cron) and give it access.

This will fix the issue